# Copy and modify a row in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need some help with a csv file. I'm working with the CIS Automotive API and am extracting data to put in a database. I turned the data into a csv file, however there are some rows with multiple ID's. Is there anyway I can copy the row but with one ID each?

The csv file is like this at the moment:

```
Dealership     | Address       |Zipcode| DealerID
Charleston Kia | 123 Bowman rd | 29412 | 12345,21456,32145
```

and I wanted to make it to look like this:

```
Dealership     | Address       |Zipcode| DealerID
Charleston Kia | 123 Bowman rd | 29412 | 12345
Charleston Kia | 123 Bowman rd | 29412 | 21456
Charleston Kia | 123 Bowman rd | 29412 | 32145
```

Comment: There are certainly many ways to accomplish this. But before any of them are recommended in code, please provide the Python code that you've written to load the CSV so far. I would recommend parsing the CSV line by line and entering sanitized data into a new data structure (that represents the parsed CSV). Doing so allows you to check for multiple DealerIDs and create individual entries accordingly.

Comment: Also, what you show is not csv file, but something like pipe-delimited of fixed-width file. And it doesn't make sense to process the interim file you create from the API, better process the API response.

Comment: Please update your question with this code instead of providing it inline here. Thanks!

Comment: @buran is right. If you get this data from an API, then you are the one creating the CSV. It doesn't make sense to write a CSV then read and parse it. You should create individual entries in the data structure you are using to store the API results (possibly a new, intermediate, data structure that you build during parsing).

Comment: Try with pandas. `df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv'); df['DealerID'] = df['DealerID'].str.split(','); df.explode('DealerID').to_csv('path/to/new/file.csv', index=False)`

Comment: It would help if you: provide sample code that shows how you obtain the data from the API and turn it into a .csv and a (perhaps partial) example of the type of response / file received from the API. Writing the data to an intermediate .csv can help in assuring you have the right data, but instead of continuing to process the intermediate result, you would do well to work off of the source data - sharing that here can help others help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Dictreader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read each row with the headers. Then, [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the *DealerID* column on commas, and replicate the row with the matching ID.

So for an input file `file.csv` like:

```
Dealership|Address|Zipcode|DealerID
Charleston Kia|123 Bowman rd|29412|12345,21456,32145
```

The following code:

```py
import csv

with open("file.csv") as file, open("new.csv", 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        for _id in row["DealerID"].split(','):
            writer.writerow({**row, "DealerID": _id})
```

Will create a new file, `new.csv` with contents:

```
Dealership,Address,Zipcode,DealerID
Charleston Kia,123 Bowman rd,29412,12345
Charleston Kia,123 Bowman rd,29412,21456
Charleston Kia,123 Bowman rd,29412,32145
```